# What is required to create magical items such as The Monster Book of Monsters?

Tags: harry-potter

I know that magic is used to transfigure/charm single items to get the desired results, but what about mass produced items like the Monster Book of Monsters?

Is there a wizard sweat shop set up where they have wizards and witches bringing each individual item to life? Or (since I'm not that well versed in Harry Potter lore) have there been instances shown where the process of creation somehow gives life to the items?

Comment: I'm gonna go with "they use magic".

Comment: @Richard *Insert magic gif here* :)

Comment: cf. the scene in *Deadly Hallows* where they sneak into the Ministry to reclaim the locket from Umbridge.  IIRC, there was a roomful of wizards making stuff - pamphlets, I think.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Turn that into an answer and you've got yourself a +1

Comment: I think they're random-generated.  If you want to create such an item, it's very costly: you have to spend significant amounts of XP for each book, and take feats, besides other requirements.  But if this book appears in the random books table, then it will be randomly spawned in dungeons, monsters' inventory, or shops' inventory, so people can collect them.  This may seem unfair, but don't forget that the random items table is (ideally) carefully balanaced, whereas when you create magical items, you make the decisions about the item, so the items could be overpowered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From chapter thirteen of *Deathly Hallows*:

> Halfway along the next corridor he emerged into a wide, open space where a dozen witches and wizards sat in rows at small desks not unlike school desks, though much more highly polished and free from graffiti.  [...] They were all waving and twiddling their wands in unison, and squares of coloured paper were flying in every direction like little pink kites.  After [...] a few more seconds he realised that what he was watching was the creation of pamphlets, that the paper squares were pages, which when assembled, folded and magicked into place, fell into neat stacks beside each witch or wizard.

Not a sweatshop per se, since the working conditions don't seem unreasonably harsh.  But the same basic approach.  Note in particular the absence of anything resembling an assembly line, and that the pamphlets are constructed one at a time rather than en masse.

(Of course the pamphlets in question did not appear to be magical in themselves, but it seems reasonable to suppose that mass-produced magical items are in general manufactured in the same way.)

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: That doesn't explain how the book gets its animalistic behaviour.

Comment: @Worse_Username, same process - a witch or wizard casts one or more charms.  There might be additional steps, e.g., perhaps the covers have to be made of the hide of some particular magical creature for the charms to work, but the books never really go into that sort of detail.