# Why is the Monster Book of Monsters the way it is?

Tags: harry-potter

When I was a kid and saw the movie I was like "well ***obviously*** the Monster Book got to be a vicious biting thing". But now it dawns on me: *what the hell?*

Is there a legitimate reason why whoever created this book decided it would be a nice idea if it attempted to bite anyone within range? Couldn't a normal textbook be enough?

The one and only thing that comes to my mind is that this is an attempt to teach young students how to handle wild creatures. But it's proven that almost no students can handle them and hence they will be wasting a lot of learning time anyway.

So, is there somewhere in canon that explains why are they produced the way they are?

Comment: I don't *think* there's anything satisfying in canon. It was probably originally just a curiosity/work of a nutter/optimistic attempt to teach people that the best way to deal with monsters is to stroke them/whatever. Only Hagrid would set it as a serious textbook. Although, bear in mind, they weren't actually very dangerous. Although, mind you, it seems that you have to stroke them to be allowed to open them. Perhaps that didn't stop them being monstrous as soon as you closed them (and therefore in need of restraining/generally totally unusable)

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you make a monstrous book that tries to bite you when you go near it?

Comment: This was going to be my follow up question to: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100207/what-is-required-to-create-magical-items-such-as-the-monster-book-of-monsters but you beat me to it. +1 :)

Comment: @kjw and that was exactly what triggered me to ask this :)

Comment: I'm not sure it's even justifiably a monster.I mean it's a pretty unusual looking thing, but hardly that different in other respects from a badger.

Comment: *Voldemort* is asking about unnecessary ferocity and violence?

Comment: It's a wonderful story part because it shows that there must be other nutters like Hagrid in this world. Do you admit that the *"Invisible Book of Invisibility"* is also magnificient ? :o))

Comment: There are quite a few books in HP that make me go _WTF?!?_ if I make the mistake of thinking about them rationally. Like the books that let out blood-curdling screams as soon as you open them, or that one you yourself Horcrucified—not to mention the invisible and monstrous ones, of course.

Answer (score 9):

Whoever made the book might have had a sense of humor.

> “Hasn’ — hasn’ anyone bin able ter open their books?” said Hagrid, looking crestfallen.
>
> The class all shook their heads.
>
> “Yeh’ve got ter stroke ‘em,” said Hagrid, as though this was the most obvious thing in the world. “Look —”
>
> He took Hermione’s copy and ripped off the Spellotape that bound it. The book tried to bite, but Hagrid ran a giant forefinger down its spine, and the book shivered, and then fell open and lay quiet in his hand.
>
> “Oh, how silly we’ve all been!” Malfoy sneered. “We should have stroked them! Why didn’t we guess!”
>
> “I — I thought they were funny,” Hagrid said uncertainly to Hermione.
>
> “Oh, tremendously funny!” said Malfoy. “Really witty, giving us books that try and rip our hands off!”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 16, Talons and Tea Leaves</sup></sub>

Imagine getting a book you cannot open or for that matter you cannot see.

> “Stop it! Stop it!” cried the manager, poking the walking stick through the bars and knocking the books apart. “I’m never stocking them again, never! It’s been bedlam! I thought we’d seen the worst when we bought two hundred copies of the Invisible Book of Invisibility — cost a fortune, and we never found them... Well... is there anything else I can help you with?”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 4, The Leaky Cauldron</sup></sub>

It looks like it is a practice used to sell more books. I can think of following factors

- Increases coolness of the book
- It makes the book different from other books
- Book can be used as a prank

Answer (score 2):

Not canon, but one reason in-universe may have been that it served as a sort of a **pre-requisite** to learning from the book. If you can't figure out how to tame the mini-monster that is the book, you're not (yet ready|worthy) to learn its contents.